# How to delete an app from the App Store with NEW iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes, testflight

I want to delete the tested app from iTunes connect.

When I searched this topic in google i got one solution but i did not get any thing if i am following this procedure.

[AppDeletionFromitunes](https://kb.applingua.com/2015/02/removing-apps-from-the-app-store-itunes-connect/)

Please help me if any solution is there

Thanks&Regards
smily

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: with out programming also so many questions are there in stackoverflow

Comment: You should vote to close them then.

Comment: Is there any reason to close the issue. It is also important for every ios developers.

Comment: It's not a programming problem, but a problem iOS programmers may face.  In iTunes Connect terms, this is an issue for the Admin role, who may not be a programmer at all.  Would you ask here how to write the description of your app on the App Store?  Would you ask here how much to charge for your app? Ask on the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: You finally can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682672/5306470

Answer (score 0):

Even in new iTunesConnect, you cannot remove applications that are in any other state than *Ready For Sale* unless it was approved at least once before.

As you wrote `a tested app` I guess it is not available on the AppStore or *Ready For Sale*. You will not be able to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete but you can hide it. Go to the Pricing tab (Rights and Pricing) and deselect all the countries. To be able to deselect all the countries click on 'specific territories'. After doing that the status of the app would change to 'Developer Removed From Sale'