# Delete App from iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

I am enable to delete the app from iTunes connect, now there is no option to delete the app from iTunesConnect.I have login with iTunesconnect and check the app setting but there is no option to delete the app.

Comment: you can't delete the app, once you have created. Thanks

Comment: You need to be a team agent to delete an App from iTunes Connect. But you can only delete an app that is approved for the app store.

Comment: If your requirement is to delete an app from iTunes Connect - It's not possible. If you want to delete it from the AppStore - You can do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer this Apple document: [Deleting an App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

You can delete your app if there is at least one approved version of the app and the latest version status is one of the following:

- Prepare for Submission
- Invalid Binary
- Developer Rejected
- Rejected
- Metadata Rejected
- Developer Removed From Sale
- Removed from Sale

If your application status different (other) than above list, refer this Apple document: [Viewing and Changing Your App’s Status and Availability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW1)

First, change your application status according to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW1) tutorial and then [delete app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) from store.

[image]

Comment: All 4 links seem dead. :(

Answer (score 6):

## October 4th 2018 Update

#### You can now delete apps, *even if never submitted*.

<s>Original link: https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/whats-new/?id=100002355</s> (link broken, like many other older Apple Developer News links...)

Comment: Reference link broken.